# How can i detect hardware accleration problems in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fullscreen, hardware-acceleration

When I used full screen in as3, application opens full screen, but it completely blank. At other computers all works fine. I searched hard and found that sometimes hardware acceleration could provoke this. I turned off hardware acceleration manually (by right-click menu on flash app > settings), and app started work in full screen correctly.

How could I detect, if client have hardware acceleration turned on, and application shows him white screen? If any possibilities to fight with this problem other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For video hardware acceleration you should use the `VideoStage` class. So if you can get an instance of the `StageVideo` class then hardware acceleration is available. How to get this instance [described here](http://help.adobe.com/en_En/as3/dev/WSe9ecd9e6b89aefd2-68d5ef8f12cc8511f6c-7ffe.html).

Comment: *"if you can get an instance of the StageVideo class then hardware acceleration is available"* - This is not true.  From your link:  *"StageVideoEvent.RENDER_STATE [..] indicates the type of decoding currently in use: hardware, software, or unavailable (nothing is displayed)."*